# On multiplicative order.

Tags: number-theory

Consider integers of form $n=pq$ where $p,q$ are distinct odd integers at least one of them prime and more than $4$ apart.

$(1)$ When does the multiplicative order of $p-1$ or $p+1$ in $\Bbb Z_n^\times$ exceed $q$?

$(2)$ When does the multiplicative order of $p-1$ or $p+1$ in $\Bbb Z_n^\times$ less than $q-1$?

$(3)$ When does the multiplicative order of $p-1$ or $p+1$ in $\Bbb Z_n^\times$ equal $q-1$?

I am interested in both $p<q$ and $q<p$.

Comment: Can you say where this is relevant and what you have tried?

Comment: I just tried some experiments. I think they never for $(1)$.

Comment: For $(p,q)=(5,7)$ we have $ord(p-1)=q-1$, so (3) holds. What exactly are you hoping for as an answer? "When does" is a bit unclear - a possible answer is just "sometimes it does, sometimes not". And why not take both $p,q$ primes?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $p$ and $q$ much different (not just different by $1$). what you have is a corner condition. I think $(1)$ is impossible and $(2)$ and $(3)$ are equally likely and that $(3)$ can be easily quantified as when it can occur based on relative properties of $p$ and $q$.